# WiFi driver not available/working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I am having windows7 on my pc and using Ubuntu 16.04 on vmware. Here I am unable to use WiFi driver on Ubuntu while WiFi is working fine for windows7. There is no WiFi driver available under system settings/additional drivers.

And no output for the following command: `lspci -knn |grep Net -A2`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the wireless device? Is it a USB or PCI device?

Comment: I am having windows 7 on pc and using vmware to run ubuntu 16.04. Now i am unable to connect to wifi on ubuntu while it is working fine on Windos7.

Comment: You don't connect to Wi-Fi from a guest system, you use the host network connection.

Comment: How can i use host network connection.Also NAT option is not ther under settings>network path. Please suggest how can i connect to wifi network via virtual desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your VM's settings and select network, then select <strike>bridged adapter</strike>.

There is no need for drivers in your case.

**Edit:**

Select NAT instead of bridged adapter

Comment: Bridge won't work in many cases. NAT will always work. It should be default.

Comment: Sorry, i did not get you guys.. i need to access internet at vmware>ubuntu OS. For that i need wifi to connect. and wifi is not working at ubuntu seems like wifi driver is missing.